# IBM Worklight to deploy to external server showing context root not found

Tags: worklight-studio, worklight-server

I done the setting below :

1. Starting ***worklightServer***
2. Run as > build and deploy target

[image: Deploy to external server]

But, when i try to open `http://192.168.0.132:9080/gaban/console` . It showing this error :

```
Context Root Not Found
```

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you have to mention the context root while building for remote server.

If you are using worklight 6.1 check this [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fdev%2Fc_building_and_deploying_in_development.html)

If you are using older versions you have to use `Run As -> Build for Remote Server' with context root.

Also you must want to deploy the WAR file in Server to see your worklight console

Comment: @MiG Did you try copying WLAPP files from `bin` and uploaded those in worklight console? Did you deployed your WAR files into external Server? AFAIK `Run As -> Build and Deploy Target` wont deploy the applications to external server. It will give you only Buillded files in Bin folder